# Why is z-index not working over border and outer div?

Tags: html, css, sass, z-index

I have a component consisting of an outer div and an inner div, within which there are two images. One image is designed to sit directly on top of the inner div's left border and the other is to sit on the right border. When I place these images where they are intended to feature, the portion of either image that is supposed to sit in the border gets hidden behind the border while the portion that overlaps beyond the inner div also becomes invisible. This is despite me setting the z-index for either image to 9999. Can anybody explain why this is the case? I've shared the relevant code below:

```css
.intro-background {
  background: linear-gradient(20deg, rgba(247, 247, 247, 1) 10%, 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 90%, 0%, rgba(247, 247, 247, 1) 10%);
}

.intro-container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 85%;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: 5px solid #666666;
  border-right: 5px solid #004d00;
}

.margin-green,
.margin-grey {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  height: auto;
  right: -20px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.margin-green {
  width: 35px;
  right: -20px;
}

.margin-grey {
  width: 34px;
  left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro-background">
  <div class="intro-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="green" class="margin-green"/>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="grey" class="margin-grey"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note: It is important that I keep these images within the inner div to ensure that they continue to align with the inner div's borders when the browser screen size is adjusted. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see no problem with your code in SOSnippet. Maybe you have somewhere `overflow: hidden` in one of parents?

Comment: Ah, yes, I have overflow-x set to hidden for the html body element. I've since tried setting the inner div's overflow-x property to visible but for some reason it's now showing a horizontal scrolling bar instead.